# Bluemix Watson Putting project on github

Tags: git, rest, github, cloud

I have a question about sharing a Watson application on github. I am planning to build a small project in Java which would use Rest Apis as I am learning about connecting to rest at the moment. The worry I have is how to share the codes and passwords for cloud services on github.

If I share my code would anybody who sees the password be able to connect to my apis and use up my requests limits?

Is there any good practice for sharing applications like that on github without sharing the passwords?

Comment: Yes there is good practice around this, don't do it. Unfortunately that's about all anyone can tell you. You need to ensure you never commit your passwords into your repository.

Comment: After I wrote the question and thought about it I could make an XML file with these passwords Credentials.xml which will be in the .gitingore file and in the APP make static variables or a Credentials objects which will read it on startup. I just want to have some code on gihub for recruiters so if they would actually ever want to run it I would send them the file.

Comment: The typical way is to add a *template* file to your repository. This would have the structure of the real file but none of the real values. This goes for both configuration files and other such files where you don't really want to expose some values such as addresses or authentication. Your build scripts could even detect the case that the real configuration is missing (fresh clone or checkout+clean for instance) and make a copy from the template which you would then have to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to have your service credentials stored in a property file.

For example `.env`.

You would add `.env` to the `.gitignore` file. Then upload a `.env.example` file which contains example settings.

With instructions for how to get the project working. This is what [conversation-simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple) does.

In the case of Java you would store it in a property file.